# Is there a way to style a lightning visual flow?

Tags: lightning

Running a lightning flow - I wish to style the look and feel of some labels and inputs - background, colors etc... Where can I inject my CSS to over-ride the default styling?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free add-on from UnofficialSF which should let you do most of this. See: [Style Your Flow with Headers, Banners, Rules, Formatting and More](https://unofficialsf.com/from-sharad-style-your-flow-with-headers-banners-rules-formatting-and-more/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CSS in Flows. However, you can still give colours to labels. Are you using flow screen inputs? If yes, then you can specify colour to input labels from flow designer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most ideal answer as it requires some customization, but you can insert your own custom lightning component into a screen element for a flow.The component itself could contain the input fields you need with more functionality than the standard flow screen input.You could modify the style (item 4 in the picture below) part of the lightning component bundle to add all of your CSS. 
[image: Lightning Bundle]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

- create a custom Lightning Component that launches your Flow with screens using the global lightning:flow component: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_cmp.htm?search_text=flow
- leverage custom CSS for your custom lightning component: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm